# Android 4.4 printing API over different connections

Tags: android, printing

I am working on Printer API for Android 4.4. My goal is to integrate printer API and giving print. For that I have done some R&D , please confirm on this

1)Using HP printer: HP service plugins are pre-installed in Android  device and assuming that this is only for HP printer models only. Please confirm on this.

2)Using Cloud print: We can use this option for other than HP printers and assuming that we can add the printer to cloud print. please confirm this.

And also please let me know how can I add a printer to Google cloud print programmatically?

3)If both Android device and Printer device supports Bluetooth, can I print the document using the Android 4.4 printer API?

4)In case of WIFI, I assume that both Android device and printer device should be in the same LAN. Please confirm on this?

4)Assume a case, my Android device is connected to WIFI and Printer device connected to physical network  but they are in the same LAN. In this case will it be possible for printing?

5)Finally, assume that if there is no internet connection in my Android device and Printer device, but I have connected my Android device to Printer(assume that printer supports USB port) using USB cable. Is it possible to print?
If yes, please let provide API/related information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this. please find the following respective answers below:

1)Yes, If you have installed HP plugins then you can connect to HP printers only.

2)Yes, we can add the printers to cloud using chrome browser but I am not sure in programmatically adding the printers to cloud

3)yes, You can

4)Both(Device and printer) should be in the same LAN

4)In that case, I assume Google cloud printing is the only option.

5)Yes, You without internet connection also you can print using USB OTG cable. But the Android device should have OTG support(Samsung Tab 5 has OTG support)